# Full Screen JavaFX Anchor Pane with title bar

Tags: javafx

I want to set full screen Anchor Pane with title Bar in JavaFX. I used the property

```
stage.setFullScreen(true);
```

but it does not show title bar. What should I do to make my Anchor Pane full screen but with title bar?

Comment: Provide some relevant code of what u have tried so far.

Comment: With title bar, do you mean the `Title of the Stage`?

Comment: Yes I want The Title Bar which has a Title  at Left Hand side and minimize ,maximize and close button at right .

Comment: The you should use `setMaximized(true)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

After using setMaximized(true); clean and build your project.

```
public class Test extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("DashBoard.fxml"));
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/com/images/icon.png"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setTitle("Dash Board");
    stage.setMaximized(true);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
```

}